# obtain ViewGroup inside Fragment.onCreate() method

Tags: android, android-fragments, viewgroup

there's a way to abtain ViewGroup inside the Fragment.onCreate() method or i can obtain just inside onCreateView ?

i would like to initialize some component before onCreateView method, so i need viewgroup to get the view

Comment: There is no `View`, or `ViewGroup` for that matter, before `onCreateView`. You can inflate your view in `onCreateView` and initialize your fields in that method though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the root view of a fragment you can call getView()

```
  /**
     * Get the root view for the fragment's layout (the one returned by {@link #onCreateView}),
     * if provided.
     * 
     * @return The fragment's root view, or null if it has no layout.
     */
    public View getView() {
        return mView;
    }
```

But this will return null until onCreateView was finished. (as Niek indicated)

You can see in FragmentManger source that mView is set through the usage of onCreateView:

```
f.mView = f.onCreateView(f.getLayoutInflater(f.mSavedFragmentState),
                container, f.mSavedFragmentState);
```

Can you elaborate why do you want to intialize something before oncreateview?